# Load and play (Round Robins) with new AKSampler and SFZ

Tags: swift, audiokit

Is there any option to load and play sample files (Round Robins) played with same velocity (AKSampler) and SFZ, to get more natural sound with variations? I have tried different things, but unfortunately with no success.

AKSampler load all files from given SFZ but play only first sample in the region.
"seq_length" should make the samples 1-4 change each time the note was played.

loop_mode=one_shot
 key=60 hivel=10 amp_velcurve_10=1 seq_length=4

seq_position=1 sample=samples/SnareOpen29.aif

seq_position=2 sample=samples/SnareOpen30.aif

seq_position=3 sample=samples/SnareOpen31.aif

seq_position=4 sample=samples/SnareOpen32.aif

Taste=60 lovel=11 hivel=21 amp_velcurve_21=1 seq_length=4

seq_position=1 sample=samples/SnareOpen33.aif

seq_position=2 sample=samples/SnareOpen34.aif

seq_position=3 sample=samples/SnareOpen35.aif

seq_position=4 sample=samples/SnareOpen36.aif

Taste=60 lovel=22 hivel=31 amp_velcurve_31=1 seq_length=4

seq_position=1 sample=samples/SnareOpen37.aif

seq_position=2 sample=samples/SnareOpen38.aif

seq_position=3 sample=samples/SnareOpen39.aif

seq_position=4 sample=samples/SnareOpen40.aif
...

seq length-function seem not to work, but maybe there is a way to implement the Round Robin function in AKSampler load SFZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Round-robins really only make sense for sampler engines that can stream sample data files from disk. AKSampler pre-loads everything into RAM, and hence isn't suitable for use with large numbers of samples (which tends to be the case when round-robins are used). Round-robins may make sense for drums, though, and I will put adding this feature on our to-do list. In the meantime, you should look into AKAppleSampler, which I believe does support round-robins.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I first worked with AKMIDISampler and because of the possibility to load compressed audio files with the new AKSampler I switched to this one. Everything works fine so far, especially the loading of the sfz files is wonderfully solved, just missing the opportunity to play at least two alternative samples alternately... But if that don’t work for now, do you have a tip / hint how to load samples from disk with AKMIDISampler and sfz... I have not seen examples of this with Audiokit.

Comment: AKAppleSampler is a wrapper around AUSampler, an Audio Unit which is built into macOS (and iOS) and accessible in Logic Pro, GarageBand, etc. If you have Logic I'd suggest setting up your samples in ESX24, because AUSampler can also read ESX24 files.

Comment: I disagree with the generalization that round-robins only make sense for streaming engines, especially now that we have so much memory.  The memory footprint depends on many factors like how many notes are sampled and note length (which is very short for a snare versus low piano notes.)  So, it's definitely true that streaming players relax the memory constraints considerably, but lack of streaming isn't necessarily a deal killer for round robins.